# Go to that other application, and click upgrade, but cannot see the upgrade button

Tags: button, upgrade

I created my first Android app called 3 Lil Letters.  I was having a problem making a signed APK.  I found a web link that showed the steps. That was great. But when I was at the last step, I had an error about a duplicate key.  It did create the apk, so I uploaded it to Google Play.  I then decided that I should try to recreate the apk so that it does not have this error.  I was able to do that so now I have an APK that I want to overwrite the existing APK.  When I try to upload it says that the apk already exists and that I need to press the UPGRADE button.  All I can see is the UPLOAD button.

I tried IE and FireFox browers and have the same problem.  I cannot find the UPGRADE button.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After uploading an `.apk` to Google Play, you have to *increment the version number* in your build to upload another one. You cannot have two different `.apk` files with the same version number. You also cannot remove an `.apk` after having uploaded it, even if it is known to be broken in some way.

Comment: OK I was thinking that that is what i could do if i could not find the update button.  If this button really doesn't exist, then Google should update their error/info messages.

Comment: Well I opened the AndroidManifest.xml with Notepad and changed the xml to read (see snippet): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.bcit.tbs.littlewords"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >  But now Eclipse says that the version is out of sync.  Now what do I do? Even changing back to 1 I still see the same error in the console.  Help.

Comment: @user1413991: Sorry, I don't use Eclipse so I'm afraid I can't help with the "version out of sync" message.